# File upload not working in oops PHP

Tags: php, oop

```
public function upload($file = array(), $where) 
{
    if (file_exists($this->src.$file['name']))
    {
        $data['error'] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
    }
    elseif ($file["name"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $data['error'] = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
    elseif(is_array($file))
    {
        if(in_array($file['type'], $this->type))
        {
            $filePath = $this->src.$file['name'];
            $file_Check = move_uploaded_file($file['name']['tmp_name'], $filePath);
            if ($file_Check)
            {
                print_r($file); die(); 
                $name = $file['name'];
                //$this->update(array('photo'=>$name,'candi_id'=>$where));
            }               
            $data['error'] = 'File has been uploaded';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error'] = 'File formet was not supported';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['error'] = 'No File was uploaded...';         
    }

    return $data;       
}
```

output:

file path show correctly. function also working fine but file not move to folder?

Comment: You checked your Folder permission ?

Comment: Consider fomatting. This is not readable.

Comment: getting this correct? `$filePath` ?? which error `$data['error']` are u getting?

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form, like

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="file" type="file">
...
</form>
```